# Web2py: Custom CSS class for custom form

Tags: python, css, web2py

How do i specify the class of a custom web2py form?
for e.g.

```
{{=form.custom.begin}}
Image name: <div>{{=form.custom.widget.name}}</div>
Image file: <div>{{=form.custom.widget.file}}</div>
Click here to upload: {{=form.custom.submit}}
{{=form.custom.end}}
```

How do i specify the CSS class for `form` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's a SQLFORM, you can specify the class when you create the form:

```
form = SQLFORM(db.mytable, _class='myclass')
```

Otherwise, `form.custom.begin` simply produces the following HTML:

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

so instead of using `form.custom.begin`, you could simply enter that HTML (with your class added) directly into the template.